# How can I pass row id in url when editing a row in admin page?

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, grid

I want to prefill my form inputs when trying to edit a row, but the ID won't pass, unless I type the exact number in the URL. Is there any way of passing the ID? Code below, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Discount\DiscountRule\Block\Adminhtml\Rule" name="discount_rule_grid">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="discount_rule_grid.grid" as="grid">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
                        <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Discount\DiscountRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection</argument>
                        <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                        <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                        <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="discount_rule_grid.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">

                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/form/index</item>
                                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">grid.columnSet.rule_id</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>

                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="rule_id">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="rule_name">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rule Name</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">rule_name</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="products">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="discount_percentage">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Percentage</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">discount_percentage</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="status">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">status</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="created_at">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_at</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="updated_at">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</argument>
                                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">updated_at</argument>
                                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed like this and now it's working.

```
<arguments>
                            <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/form/index</item>
                                <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getRuleId</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
```